# Random seed for reproducibility for MCMC sampler in pymc

Tags: python, pymc, mcmc

I have constructed a hierarchical model (in pymc) with 5 stochastic variables and a single deterministic variable and I want to be able to set a random seed so that the sampler is able to reproduce identical traces.

I've tried various things like setting *rseed* (for stochastics) and also numpy.random.seed at the beginning of my model but I am unable to reproduce the traces.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import pymc

#level 3
a1 = pymc.Beta('a1', alpha=1, beta=1)
a2 = pymc.Gamma('a2', alpha=0.1, beta=0.1)

#level 2
b1 = pymc.Beta('b1', alpha = (a1 * a2) + 1, beta = ((1-a1) * a2) + 1, size = 8)
b2 = pymc.Gamma('b2', alpha=0.1, beta=0.1, size = 8)

#level 1
c = pymc.Beta('c', alpha = data['alpha'], beta = data['beta'])

# Likelihood scoring
d = pymc.Binomial('d', n = data['n'], p = c, value = data['obs'], observed=True)

# The model
model = pymc.Model([a1,a2,b1,b2,c,d])
mcmc = pymc.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(iter=50000, burn=10000, thin=20)
```

I am using Python 2.7 and pymc version 2.3.6

Comment: Is this related? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95514/pymc-random-seed-doesnt-guarantee-the-same-posterior-samples

Comment: Yes. I saw this and implemented it in my code but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I suggest creating an issue on github: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc